# WooCommerce Subscription extension - Expiration date shows 1970

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use the WooCommerce Subscription extension to add subscription products to my online shop.

I set up a product which is valid for 6 months. However if somebody orders this product the ordering date is set correct, but the expiration date says 1st January 1970. Did I miss a setting somewhere?

Would be great if someone knows the answer!

Comment: You should contact [Woothemes Support](https://support.woothemes.com) for questions about their premium extensions.

Comment: Thanks. Figured it out - it was just the default date because the payment was not done.